# COM interface disappears from ROT

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, mfc

I have two applications, both of which I have written.
AppA was written in C++ using MFC. During startup it registers a CSingleDocTemplate and creates a document. The document provides a COM interface and registers itself in the ROT:

```
  LPUNKNOWN punk = GetInterface(&IID_Welder); // doesn't AddRef
  ::RegisterActiveObject(punk, CLSID_Interface, ACTIVEOBJECT_WEAK, &m_dwRegister);
```

AppA revokes the entry in the ROT when it is destroyed:

```
  if (m_dwRegister)
    ::RevokeActiveObject(m_dwRegister, NULL);
```

The destructor is only called when AppA terminates.

AppB is written in C# and is a client of the interface provided by AppA:

```
private void Connect()
  {
  welderInterface = (Welder.Interface)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Welder.Interface");
  Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(welderInterface);    // AddRef's it ...
  }
```

private void Disconnect()
  {
  if (welderInterface != null)
    {
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(welderInterface);
    welderInterface = null;
    }
  }
(error handling omitted for clarity)

That all works perfectly the first time AppB runs after AppA has started; AppB can call `Connect` and `Disconnect` as often as it wants and use the interface between. However, if AppB terminates and runs again (AppA still running) the interface is no longer available - `Marshal.GetActiveObject` throws an exception from `MK_E_UNAVAILABLE`. The only way to make the interface available again is to restart AppA - not an acceptable solution!

Please can someone suggest how I might fix this?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but have you tried using GetRunningObjectTable and CreateBindCtx to access the ROT and get your COM interface instead. Does this approach have the same issue?

Comment: No I haven't tried that but I have no reason to suppose it would be any different. I think the problem is somewhere in the MFC code (or the way I'm using it). I may try it if I get time. I believe I will have to p/Invoke those functions. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes using GetRunningObjectTable will involve P/Invoke. Please see the following for a related example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268483/getting-running-visual-studio-2010-instances-and-programmatically-attaching-to-a/3268736#3268736

Comment: Heres an article that shows how to go about doing that http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/automatingvisualstudio.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 ::RegisterActiveObject(punk, CLSID_Interface, ACTIVEOBJECT_WEAK, &m_dwRegister);
```

ACTIVEOBJECT_WEAK is your problem here.  From the RegisterActiveObject docs:

*Weak registration keeps a pointer to the object in the running object table, but does not increment the reference count. Consequently, when the last external connection to a weakly registered object disappears, OLE releases the object's stub, and the object itself is no longer available.*

Which is exactly what's happening in your program.  Trivially solve the problem with ACTIVEOBJECT_STRONG.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The interface was being deleted when AppB disconnected even though the MFC document that implemented it was still alive. I had delved fairly deep in the MFC code and not found anything but it must be happening somewhere in there.

I AddRef'd the interface in the doc constructor and Release'd it in the destructor and the problem was solved.